# Need help figuring how to place 2 divs

Tags: html, css

Cant seem to put a box next to the body and have it be stick (a.k.a follow the scroll wheel) 
[Concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWRIK.png)
Ive got this attempt code but it's not working

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 60%;
  display: block;
}

#a {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

#b {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
</div>
<div id="b">
  BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
</div>
```

Comment: Add minimal working code

Comment: Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, [read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think "Position: fixed" is what you are looking for.

```css
body,
html {
    height: 100%;
}

html {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

body {
    width: 60%;
    padding: 30px;
    height: 4000px; /* TEST */
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#site-block {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  right: 0px;
  max-width: 15%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>

  <div id="site-block">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>

</body>
```